# Работа с кодом php из скрипта jquery

Tags: jquery, php

Имею некий цикл, выводит новости с кнопками для их редактирования.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["news_t"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["news"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href=modules\edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'>Редактировать</a></td>';
    echo '<td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".del'.$row["id"] .'").click(function(){
    if (confirm("Уверены, что хотите удалить новость:\n'.$row["news_t"].' ?")) {
    alert("Сейчас новость `'.$row["news_t"].'` будет удаленна!");
    }
    });
});
</script>
<a class="del'.$row["id"] .'" href="modules\ed.php?idel='.$row['id'].'">Удалить</a>
</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Данный скрипт при нажатие на кнопку Удалить выводит мне подтверждение и если я нажимаю да, то меня переводит на другую страничку. 
А мне бы хотелось сделать вот так

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["news_t"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["news"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href=modules\edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'>Редактировать</a></td>';
    echo '<td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".del'.$row["id"] .'").click(function(){
    if (confirm("Уверены, что хотите удалить новость:\n'.$row["news_t"].' ?")) {
    **Тут я хотел бы вставить код на удаление новости, ну т.е
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `news` WHERE (id = '$idel')")**
    alert("Новость `'.$row["news_t"].'` будет удаленна!");
    }
    });
});
</script>
<a class="del'.$row["id"] .'" href="modules\ed.php?idel='.$row['id'].'">Удалить</a>
</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Можно ли как то вклинить код туда?

Comment: передавайте аяксом нужный id, если все прошло хорошо, возвращайте сообщение Новость такая-то удалена

Comment: Можете код подсказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во второй строке давайте строке таблицы какой-то id:

```
printf('<tr id="tr%s">', $row['id']);
```

А при нажатии на кнопку, после подтверждения, что «Да, хочу стереть» пусть будет ajax-звонок на URL для удаления по id:

```
var postid = $(this).attr('id'); // если кликают по кнопке DEL у которой id= id строки
$.post( '/modules/delete.php', { id: postid }, function( response){
    // сюда попадаем когда получен ответ от delete.php
    // надо круто убрать строку таблицы как минимум,
    // или разобрать ответ сервера в переменной response - вдруг сломалось что?
    $('#tr' + postid).hide();
});
```